# Bernoulli's equation + Torricelli's law: does the speed of the fluid change if we change the area of the hole but not the height?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Let's say we have a Torricelli's Law apparatus, where, in the picture below, we are concerned about the velocity *v* coming out of the bottom-most spigot that is a height *h* below the top of the water.

[image]

The law states that $V=\sqrt{2gh}$. Essentially, the speed of the efflux in a Torricelli apparatus is directly proportional to and affected only by the height of the fluid above it.

We also know, however, that in fluid dynamics, volume flow rate is constant, demonstrated quantitatively by the continuity equation $Av = \textrm{constant},$ or $$A_1v_1 = A_2v_2\iff v_1 = \frac{A_2}{A_1}\cdot v_2$$

We can interpret this as: v is inversely proportional to the area of the hole of the container it is flowing through.

My question is now this: if we changed the area of the spigot - ever so slightly making it greater or less, but not so much as to deem the hole too big for Torricelli's Law to work - but kept the height *h* of the hole the same, would velocity change (as the continuity equation would suggest), or stay the same (as Torricelli's Law would suggest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The velocity would stay the same no matter whether the area is slightly increased or decreased provided the hole is at the same height and is quantified by        $V=\sqrt{2gh}$

And at the same time continuity principle isn't violated.Where you've gone wrong is comparing the same thing. It should be like ..

**Case 1 : Area increased**

Velocity stays the same,but the flow rate increases.

Area at exit point (A2) increased and velocity (V2) stays the same.
Similarly cross-sectional area of the tank (A1) is the same but the velocity with which the water moves down (V1) increases emptying the tank quickly as the flow rate is high.

So (A1V1)=(A2V2)  ------ since if A2 raises then V1 raises.

**Case 2 : Area decreased**

Velocity stays the same,but the flow rate decreases.

Area at exit point (A2) decreased and velocity (V2) stays the same.
Similarly cross-sectional area of the tank (A1) is the same but the velocity with which the water moves down (V1) decreases emptying the tank comparitively slowly as the flow rate is low.

So (A1V1)=(A2V2)  ------ since if A2 decrease then V1 too decreases.

Comment: Hm, I see what you're saying. So essentially you are taking into consideration the cross sectional area at the top and velocity of the water going down from there. However, doesn't Torricelli's Law say that the velocity of the water going down from the top is negligible, which is what made crossing out V1 on the left side of Bernoulli's equation possible in the first place?

Comment: yup ... exactly, but we are talking of very slight changes here which doesn't rule out Toricelli's law from working

Comment: If the velocity V1 from the top, then, is negligible, how is your statement "but the velocity with which the water moves down (V1) increases, emptying the tank quickly as the flow rate is high" valid?

Comment: Ah, so then that change in velocity V1 is also only ever so slightly increased?

Comment: Yeah but , we shouldn't forget the fact that Toricelli's law involves a simplification and moreover negligible doesn't mean zero right.

Comment: But that slight increase in velocity is multiplied by a huge area in comparision to the area of a tiny little hole.

Comment: Oh, yes! We assume negligibility for problem-solving purposes but know it is not so in the real world, just like we assume a massless rope in tension problems or 0 air resistance in projectile motion problems. Eureka!

Comment: You seem so excited :) ... Happy solving .

Comment: Thank you, my friend! I appreciate your insight and time taken to help me! :-)

Comment: Knight, one more question - if the volume flow rate of a fluid in a container is always constant, quantitatively demonstrated by the continuity equation, then why is it allowed to go up here? Does the change in A2 thus violate the conservation of mass that must underlie all fluid flow?

Comment: Sorry for being too late ,

Comment: No Zach , volume flow rate is not going to be always the same , it depends on various factors namely the pressure difference between inlet and outlet,the viscosity of the fluid,the height difference between them and certain other minute factors, if you change any of these factors then obviously volume flow rate is going to change.**Continuity Principle** essentially states that what flows in only that must flow out nothing more nothing less i.e., inlet flow = outlet flow provided the density doesn't change .Because any difference between them would mean that mass is created or destroyed.

Comment: Continuity principle is a consequence of law of conservation of mass.

Comment: Hey, no worries man! Since we are dealing with the same fluid - water, in this instance - then density mustn't change. What I still don't get is why, in the Torricelli apparatus, volume flow rate changes. What is it in the apparatus that allows it to change?

Comment: WAIT! Is it because we are using different containers with different A2's to compare the volume flow rate that it is allowed to "change?"

Comment: To make it a bit easier let's assume the increase in A2 as an entirely new hole at the same height as the previous hole ..then it makes it clear that volume flow rate is more as there are two ways in which water could escape. ..... I guess where you're messing up is considering the continuity principle and the toricelli's law in a single picture . We are talking of very very slight area (A2 <<< A1) .

Comment: I think you're quite right - I'm putting them in the same picture although continuity only applies to changes in area in a single container where a fluid flows from an inlet to an outlet; with my hypothetical on Torricelli's law, however, we are considering changes to the same point in an apparatus rather than two different points. I believe I understand it now. Thank you once again, Knight! You deserve those best answer points :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the cross section of the hole, the velocity *v2* according to Torricelli will stay the same. Bernoullis equation will also hold! There is no contradiction because when the water flow *A2·v2* at the hole increases due to the larger hole diameter the velocity *v1* of the water surface in the vessel will increase so that *A1·v1=A2·v2* still holds.

Comment: So when we are looking at the continuity equation in this context, we do not make A1 and A2 the two different areas of the exit hole, but rather look at A1 as the cross sectional area at the top and A2 as the area of the exit hole - is that correct?

Comment: You are correct! The continuity equation of Bernoulli holds for the flow in the cylindrical vessel with cross sectional area A1 with velocity v1 und the flow  through the hole with area A2 and velocity v2. (You have one hole only in this set up.) So if you increase A2 and v2 stays the same, then v1 of the water surface in the vessel has to increase because the cross sectional area of the vessel A1 is the same.

Comment: Ah, I see. But how do we know that the v2 stays the same? Is it just because of Torricelli's law where v = sqrt(2gh)?

Comment: Yes you are right! The velocity v2 at the increased hole stays the same according to Torricelli's law.

Comment: Thus, the change in the area A2 of the exit hole is compensated by the velocity V1 of the water at the top. I get it! Thank you so much, friend :-)

Comment: Yes, you are completely right!